# Creating a Conditional Statement that Applies Rules Based on the Number of Characters

Tags: jquery, if-statement, conditional-statements, character

I am stuck in a situation where I have a container with a single line of text, perfectly centered. Occasionally, the text is longer, and it breaks onto a second line. This throws off the layout, so I need a solution. I am thinking of using jquery to say, "if the number of characters goes above 28 characters, then apply a margin-top of -10px to center the text."

How would you go about this in jquery? That is, creating a conditional statement that applies rules based on the number of characters? Here is my html, the span class of `redstrip` needs a margin-top of -10 if the number of characters goes above 28 characters:

```
<a href="#">
    <img src="images/dummy3.jpg" alt="dummy">
    <span class="redStrip">Here is a bunch of dummy text that is a bit too long</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Using character count with any *non*-monospace font will be unreliable. For instance, there are both 10 characters: MMMMMMMMMM and iiiiiiiiii. Why have you preemptively chosen this solution instead of just asking how to achieve vertical alignment?

Comment: that is a great thought. Your right, I should should for vertical alignment, but I have never had great luck with that in the past

Comment: I think you'll find this solution to be a hack eventually. This is definitely something you can use CSS to solve.

Comment: how would you vertically align this? The size of the container is fixed.

Comment: You'd need to post a separate question, with your HTML and CSS.  As it stands now, it's not clear why you'd need negative margin. We'd need to see your current CSS, that's important.

Comment: your right, ill repost and then put the link up here in a few

Comment: new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8954789/vertically-sligning-text-in-a-fixed-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Anthony's answer is spot on, it'll only work for singular elements because of the behavior of `.text()` on jQuery wrapped sets with multiple elements. (i.e. if `.redstrip` selected more than one DOM element, a simple `if` wouldn't cut it).

Expanding on his answer, you may want to apply a callback filter, or an `.each()`.

```
// via filter
var redStrip = $('.redStrip');
redStrip
    .filter(function () { return $(this).text().length > 28 })
    .css('margin-top','-10px')
    ;

// via .each()
var redStrip = $('.redStrip');
redStrip.each(function () {
    var $t = $(this);
    if ($t.text().length > 28) {
        $t.css('margin-top','-10px');
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Two good solutions to solve the problem for multiple elements matched by the selector.

Answer (score 1):

Is the content constant once the page has loaded, or is it updated by user interaction with the page? Assuming the former, you can just do this:

```
var redStrip = $('.redStrip');
if(redStrip.text().length > 28) {
    redStrip.css('margin-top', '-10px');
}
```

If you're dynamically updating the content of `redStrip`, you could always wrap the above code in a function and also call that every time you do.

**EDIT**: Make that `'-10px'` in the `.css()` call.

Comment: yes, thank you, but I need it for multiple elements, I should have mentioned that