# Vertically aligning text in a fixed area

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a series of elements that have a picture with a block underneath it containing text. Occasionally, the text becomes too long and breaks onto a second line. It looks like this:

[image]

I need to vertically align the text so it is always centered. I created a jsfiddle here to help provide an answer: http://jsfiddle.net/WDChT/

Any ideas how I can do this given my html/css?

Comment: Have you considered what will happen if the text goes to a third line? In this case, fixed height will be working against you, and in fact removing it will solve this problem as well. So, it must be the same height? Just want to confirm, it looks like this is your only requirement/obstacle.

Comment: well, lets assume it doesn't go to a third line!

Comment: all the heights need to remain consistent, so if one element did break to a third line, all the heights would need to grow, and the single line text would still need to be centered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the container box:

```
line-height:60px;
height:60px;
```

inner box:

```
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QMGf/

note that inline-block doesn't work with older IEs, but the result will not be so bad

HTH

Comment: Exactly how do you define "older IEs"?  Thanks.

Comment: For anyone reading this:  will not work reliably in anything less than IE 8.  Source:  http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle`:

http://jsfiddle.net/WDChT/3/

What I added:

```
span.redStrip {
    padding:0 11px;
    height:36px;
}
span.redStrip p {
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:table-cell;
    height:36px;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Few things to note:

- Support is lacking in older versions of IE (what else is new?)
- You have `<p>` inside `<span>` which is invalid. You should wrap them in reverse: `<span>` inside `<p>`. I used your original markup for the demo.
- I moved your padding to the inner element (the `<p>` with the vertical alignment set) and removed it from the outer element (the wrapper `<span>`). Once again, these elements should be reversed.